# How to apply something like @Lazy to Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch project with multiple jobs (job A, job B, job C,...). When I run a particular job A, I got the log of the job A shows that all of the beans of job B, C,... are created too. Is there any way to avoid the creation of the other beans when job A is launched.

I have tried to use @Lazy annotation but it 's seem not working.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("springDataSource")
    public DataSource springDataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("batchJobDataSource")
    public DataSource batchJobDataSource;

}


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:partner.properties")
public class B extends BatchConfiguration {


    @Value("${partnerId}")
    private String partnerId;

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public Job ProcessB(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
      return jobBuilderFactory
        .get("ProcessB")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(listener)
        .start(ProcessStepB())
        .build();
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public Step (ProcessStepB() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("(ProcessStepB")
                .<PartnerDTO, PartnerDTO> chunk(1)
                .reader(getPartner())
                .processor(process())
                .writer(save())
                .build();
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public Reader getPartner() {    
        return new Reader(batchJobDataSource,partnerId);
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public Processor process() {
        return new Processor();
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    HistoryWriter historyWriter() {
        return new HistoryWriter(batchJobDataSource);
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    UpdateWriter updateWriter() {
        return new UpdateWriter(batchJobDataSource);
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter<PartnerDTO> saveTransaction() {
        List<ItemWriter<? super PartnerDTO>> delegates = new ArrayList<>();
        delegates.add(updateWriter());
        delegates.add(historyWriter());
        CompositeItemWriter<PartnerDTO> itemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
        itemWriter.setDelegates(delegates);
        return itemWriter;
    }
}
```

I have also put the @Lazy over the @Configuration but it does work too.

Comment: What's the problem if the beans of other jobs are created eagerly?

Comment: If my Batch have multiple jobs (Ex: 20 jobs, the number of beans are around 100). When I use Spring Cloud Data Flow to start particular job in my Batch. It executes java - jar and load all beans included beans which do not used for that job. And I think it will effect the time to load all the beans every 1 job launch.

Answer (score 1):

That should not be an issue. But here are a few ideas to try:

- Use Spring profiles to isolate job beans
- If you use Spring Boot 2.2+, try to activate the [lazy bean initialization mode](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/14/lazy-initialization-in-spring-boot-2-2)
- Package each job in its own jar. This is the best option IMO.

Comment: Tks for your advices. I'll try the 2nd option. However, I do not know about your 1st solution. Could you give me some guides or documents. About packaging each job in its own jar, that means if I have 100 jobs (actually, this number in my cases might be larger) so I need to have 100 jars? And this make me confuse the purpose of --spring.batch.job.names in Spring Cloud Data Flow.

Comment: For Spring profiles feature, take a look here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles. You can define a profile per job to load only the beans of that job. For the jar per job packaging model, yes, you will have as many jars as jobs. That's really not an issue: each job will have its own lifecycle (if you fix a bug in a job, you don't need to redeploy all of them), logs will be separated by design, beans will be separated by design (like your actual issue), and all the advantages of making one thing do one thing and do it well.

Comment: Using lazy might be effected. Because all bean are not initialized at the first time but when application is started, there beans are called? I do not know which part is responsible for that (which called beans job after application started?). However,  I confused that what happenes if I do not define my reader, processor and writer as a Bean? Are there any problems with my job?