# multiple spring boot batch jobs in one jar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, maven-3

I have multiple spring boot batch job which I want to bundle in one jar and then pass the application name from command line. Each batch job has its own configuration class. However I am running into duplicate bean issue while trying to run any one of the batch  job for repository bean. The beans are shared among the batch jobs.

`The bean 'repository' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.`

Here is one of the main batch job.

```
    package com.batch.common.invoice;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("com.batch.common.invoice.config")
    public class InvoiceNotifJob {
       SpringApplication.run(InvoiceNotifJob.class, args);
    }
```

And here one of the config class:

```
    package com.batch.common.invoice.config;
    
    @Component
    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @ComponentScan("com.batch")
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={"com.batch.core.model.repository"})
    @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.batch.core.model.entity"})
    public class SpringBatchConfig {
       ...
       //Configuration for job, step, reader, writer etc...
    }
```

All Batch jobs have similar main application class and config classes.

If I use profile id while maven build then I need to package separate jar for each batch job, which is very difficult to manage.

Need help with packaging multiple batch jobs in one jar file.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add, one of your batch bean  code in order to see how you are profiling it.

Comment: @M.Mas. Added the sample batch job and config class.

Comment: Do you really need to package all jobs in the same monolithic jar? If you package each job in its own jar, your issue will be solved by design. I recommend the jar per job packaging approach for all the good reasons of making one thing do one thing and do it well, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216804/5019386.